# How to get CConstPointer in Swift?

Tags: swift, cgaffinetransform, const-pointer

I want to transform a CGPath with the transform `CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(radians)` but the `CGPathCreateCopyByTransformingPath` func takes a `CConstPointer<CGAffineTransform>`.  How do I get a `CConstPointer<CGAffineTransform>` out of my `CGAffineTransform`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Pass the CGAffineTransform as an inout expression (that is, prefix it with `&`).

```
var xform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(3)
let newPath = CGPathCreateCopyByTransformingPath(originalPath, &xform)
```

Note that the transform must be a variable, not a Swift constant (declared with `let`).

c.f. [Using Swift with Cocoa and Objective-C: Interacting with C APIs](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/buildingcocoaapps/InteractingWithCAPIs.html)